# how to make Semantic UI dropdown with allowAdditions work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am trying to have a Semantic UI dropdown menu which allows additions but I can seem to make it work. Indeed the `Add <b>{term}</b>` message that is supposed to appear when adding something never seem to show up.

Here is a very simple example to test it http://jsfiddle.net/pybxztu2/8/

If type `johny` in the search the message doesn't show. Though if I press enter it is going through the `onChange` function.

In addition, is it even possible to have such a menu where it would be able to add `bob`: even with the `forceSelection: false` it takes `boby` by default...

Maybe I am just missing something in the Semantic UI doc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not properly documented in examples, but all you have to do is added another option in the dropdown initialisation like this:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
  allowAdditions: true,
  forceSelection: false,
  hideAdditions: false, // this line
  onChange: function(value, text) {
    document.getElementById('output_span').innerHTML = text
  },
});
```

This will show `Add <name>` in the dropdown

The property is mentioned in the settings tab

> hideAdditions: When disabled user additions will appear in the results menu using a specially formatted selection item formatted by templates.addition.